# docker AWS fail to launch - custom kernel

Tags: docker

I cannot launch docker on my AWS instance:

```
root@system:~# docker -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 -H 
unix:///var/run/docker.sock -d 

root@system:~# INFO[0000] +job serveapi(tcp://127.0.0.1:2375, unix:///var/run/docker.sock) 
INFO[0000] +job init_networkdriver()                    
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on tcp (127.0.0.1:2375)   
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock) 
Unable to allow incoming packets: iptables failed: iptables --wait -I 
  FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT:
  iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
(exit status 1)
INFO[0000] -job init_networkdriver() = ERR (1)          
FATA[0000]  (exit status 1)
```

How would you troubleshoot that error sequence message?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the [docker installation procedure on AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html):

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum update -y
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum install -y docker
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo service docker start
Starting cgconfig service:                             [  OK  ]
Starting docker:                                       [  OK  ]
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo usermod -a -G docker ec2-user
# Log out and log back in again to pick up the new docker group permissions.
# Verify that the ec2-user can run Docker commands without sudo.
[ec2-user ~]$ docker info
```

Comment: >Thanks for your response. Already I've gone through the above link.. well.. I am using Slackware 14.1 and custom kernel running instance on AWS.

Comment: In Slackware we used to start /etc/rc.d/rc.docker start and log will be created and getting the below error 
>Unable to allow incoming packets: iptables failed: iptables --wait -I FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name. (exit status 1) time="2015-05-11T04:29:49Z" level="info" msg="-job init_networkdriver() = ERR (1)" time="2015-05-11T04:29:49Z" level="fatal" msg=" (exit status 1)"
>reset the iptables rules as below

Comment: iptables -nvL
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination        
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination        
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0          
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0          
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 21 packets, 7920 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Comment: @Jai Note: Slackware version 14.1 was released in November 2013 and shipped with Linux 3.10.17, That is *just* the minimum kernel level for docker to work. You might experience some side-effect from that old kernel.

Comment: docker info is not working since getting error when it is started.. kernel version:3.10http://stacklet.com/download/kernel/linux-3.12-x86_64-virtual-guest

Comment: @Jai OK. As long as `docker info` doesn't work, I wouldn't expect anything else to work. My point is: I am not sure if a Slackware 14.1 is fully compatible with the current docker 1.x.

Comment: thanks for the response.. docker is working on my Local slackware 14.1 full installation.. default kernel.. but it is not working on AWS Slack custom kernel instances ..root@192:~# docker run -i -t vbatts/slackware bash
Pulling repository vbatts/slackware
638863f470f6: Download complete
44f48d2a5428: Download complete
Status: Downloaded newer image for vbatts/slackware:latest
bash-4.2# ls
README bin boot dev etc home lib lib64 media mnt opt proc root run sbin srv sys tmp usr var

Comment: @Jai maybe aws support has more on the difference between a local slackware, and one provided on the cloud?

Comment: root@system:~# docker info Containers: 0
Images: 0 Storage Driver: devicemapper  Pool Name: docker-202:1-394941-pool  Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB  Data file: ar/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Data Space Used: 305.7 MB  Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 733.2 kB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Library Version: 1.02.79 (2013-08-13)
Execution Driver: native-0.2 Kernel Version: 3.12.42.stk.x86-64
Operating System: Slackware 14.1
CPUs: 1